# Checking user's homepage in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Google displays a popup that asks if you want to set your home page as google.com. It's quite normal, when I say OK it sets it as google.com. After that however, I don't get the popup anymore. As far as I know, nobody should be able to retrieve the value of my homepage because it's a private info. But somehow Google is tracking it. I get the popup back when I set my homepage as a different site. I deleted the cookies but even then it is only displayed when I set homepage as another site.

I tested this behavior on IE8 & IE9. The popup never shows up in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Do you have the Google toolbar installed?

Comment: just becuase your paranoid, doesn;t mean they are not watching you

Comment: @Birk Not on IE9, I'm checking IE8.

Comment: If it's only happening in IE, it could be VBscript

Comment: @Ian It might be any script if only IE allows it...

Comment: this is the fastest upvoted question I have seen

Comment: Did you install ChromeFrame or some other plugin? I can not reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: It may be checking whether the pages of type browser is Google or not. If it's not Google it may give pop-up. That's what I think

Comment: It might just be that a webpage is able to determine some basics about itself if it is the default homepage or if it is bookmarked rather then determine what the default homepage is.

Comment: Where is this pop-up? I don't get any (I have IE 8 on XP, no other taskbars etc).

Comment: @Voitcus That's true. I forgot IE has special statements/methods that could be used too

Comment: Have you tried Googling it?

Comment: Open this in ie: http://jsfiddle.net/nW35S/

Comment: Yes, I can see it too - I have no Google taskbars.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları By "popup", do you mean a little box on the Google page? Or do you mean a dialog or actual popup window?

Comment: @RodrigoAssis Yes that shows how to **set** the homepage, but doesn't show how to **detect** what the current homepage already is.

Comment: A little off-topic, from an English person's point of view: your forename is fantastic.

Comment: @F4r-20 You are the one who both voted to close and reopen the post.

Comment: @Antony Sometimes when there are 4 closed votes you can add one more to close it and the ask to reopen right away to reset the counter :)

Comment: @Lipis Or you can just wait until the post is closed and cast a reopen vote, like I did.

Comment: @F4r-20 Yeah, at least it's not prononunced as you think.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, it's a perfectly valid programming question.  Maybe close-voters would feel more comfortable if title replaced "How does Google know my homepage" with "How can I know my users' homepage"?  It'd be a complete aesthetic change, though, the question and answers wouldn't change at all...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Changed as suggested. It's a real question because I was asked to implement the same behavior and I didn't know how.

Comment: @F4r-20 Ufuk is Turkish, but in Arabic the word means "horizon". And it's not pronounced as you think.

Comment: The best site for this question could be http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Internet Explorer makes it possible to ask it whether a given URL is the home page, it's detailed on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That links to [this example page](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/behaviors/homepage1.htm) demonstrating the API.

Comment: when i verify the example page,i get always false...am i the only one?

Comment: I've got that problem, too. But it's because it says `The isHomePage method will always return false if the document that is calling the isHomePage method is not on the same domain. For example, if www.microsoft.com is set as your homepage, and you call this method from a page on the Microsoft® Web site, then the isHomePage method returns true. However, if your homepage is set to www.microsoft.com and you call this method from a page on a different domain, the method will return false.` and the sample page is located on `http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com`, not on `http://msdn.com`.

Answer (score 26):

The code Google uses can be viewed here:

```
google.promos.mgmhp.isGoogleHomepage = function (a) {
    var b = !1;
    try {
        b = window.external.isGoogleHomePage()
    } catch (d) {
        if (h(a)) return !0;
        var c = google.promos.gpd(a, "mgmhp_hp_url");
        c && g.push(c);
        for (c = 0; c < g.length; c++) {
            var k = g[c];
            if (b = b || a.isHomePage(k)) return !0
        }
    }
    return b
};
```

They are using the proprietary isHomePage method to check if google.com is your homepage. [More info here.](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/behaviors/homepage1.htm)

Comment: A classic example of Web Development... view-source is your friend ;-)

Answer (score 10):

The following css code is the culprit.

behavior: url(#default#homePage) url(#default#userData);

this is why I don't really like IE. The behavior url(#default#userData) tells the browser to store this as session information on the client side or browser memory.

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533015(v=vs.85).aspx